# How to play a video while it is loading in Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, netstream, flvplayback

I have a problem in Flash with AS3 to playing a video mp4, this is a H.264 video with AAC, I try to play video while it is loading as any web site, but my code doesn't work, I have two codes:

1. Using FLVPlayback:

   ```
   var par:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;

   //vidRepFla is my FLVPlayback       
   vidRepFla.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY,vid_ready);
   vidRepFla.addEventListener(VideoProgressEvent.PROGRESS,vid_progress);

   vidRepFla.isLive = true;
   vidRepFla.bufferTime = 1;

   vidRepFla.play(par.source);

   function vid_ready(e:VideoEvent):void{
       trace('Playing!');
       vidRepFla.play();
   }

   function vid_progress(e:VideoProgressEvent){
       trace(e.bytesLoaded);
   }
   ```
2. Using NetStream:

   ```
   var par:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
   var video:Video;
   var connect_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); 
   connect_nc.connect(null);
   var stream_ns:NetStream = new NetStream(connect_nc);
   stream_ns.client = this;

   video = new Video();
   addChild(video);    

   stream_ns.bufferTime = 1;

   video.attachNetStream(stream_ns);
   stream_ns.play(par.source);
   ```

Do you know if I need something more or if this type video don't work the bufferTime?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear: which of your codes does not work? Both? What does it mean "does not work"? Does it throw a compiler error? Runtime error? Or it just simply doesn't play/buffer correctly?

Comment: It doesn't play/buffer correctly, the video plays only when fully loaded

Answer (score 0):

I work with Netstream and use a different method. I did notice something on the Adobe documentation for this. I read that the bufferTime setting Only works on flv files, this could be the problem since you are using mp4.

More information here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html